# Extract double quoted strings from a string, without the quotes itself

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string like `'there goes "something here", and "here" and I have "nothing else to say"'`.
I need a regex to retrieve exactly `['something here', 'here', 'nothing else to say']`. Note that the results aren't quote-escaped, this is because I don't want to make a second call for `replace(/"/g, '')` on each match.

For reference, this:

```
'there goes "something here", and "here" and I have "nothing else to say"'.match(/".*?"/g)
```

Gives me this:

```
['"something here"', '"here"', '"nothing else to say"']
```

However, like I said, I dont want the results to be quote-scaped and make a `replace` call on each result.

Answer (score 1):

This should work  `"([^"]*)"`
and here is an example test:
https://regex101.com/r/CjK2fp/1

Comment: Thanks for your time, although the answers should be in JavaScript and return an array.

Answer (score 1):

For when there should be a `\w` after first quotation mark:

```js
string = 'there goes "something here", and "here" and I have "nothing else to say"';
regexp = /(?<=")\w.*?(?=")/g
result = string.match(regexp);
console.log(result);
```

Accounting for there to be spacing between quotation mark and content:

```js
let string = 'there goes " something here ", and "here" and I have "nothing else to say"';

function everyOther(string) {

let regexp = /(?<=").*?(?=")/g

let answerArray = [];

for (; ; ) {
    if (regexp.lastIndex !== 0) {
        regexp.lastIndex += 2;
    }
    let matchArr = regexp.exec(string);
    if (regexp.lastIndex === 0) { 
        break;
    } 
    let match = matchArr[0]
    answerArray.push(match);
}

console.log(answerArray);

}

everyOther(string);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time! I just updated my question containing what I've tried and it is pretty much your  approach :)

Comment: Okay, so you want it to look exactly like `['something here', 'here', 'nothing else to say']`? Will give it a try!

Comment: Exactly. No quotes in the result array. I've just got it to work, but the solution looks pretty... exotic:
`Array.from('the string here'.matchAll(/"([^"]+)"/g), e => e[1])`
I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: @Henri Tell me if this is alright. Happy to explain too

Comment: That does work for the given string, but this would break on the following:
`'there goes " something here"'`, for example.

Comment: @Henri That's true, I'm presuming correct spacing/grammar. Want me to have a go at making a rule when this isn't the case?

Comment: Sure! Like I said, I'd love to have a working regex using your approach, as `Array.from` requires the latest JavaScript. :(

Comment: @Henri I can think of a way but it'd involve a `for` loop. Interested?

Comment: @Henri Updated answer so that it uses `regexp` and accounts for there being grammatically-incorrect spacing.

Answer (score 0):

By using some of the latest JS features

```
let reg = /"(.*?)"/gi;
let results = str.matchAll(reg);

// results - is not an array, but an iterable object
// convert results to an Array
results =  Array.from(results); 

// using map method to get second items from each array item
// which is a captured group
results = results.map(item => item[1]);
```

More info => [javascript.info ::: matchAll with groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#searching-for-all-matches-with-groups-matchall)